# How do I add a CPP defininition within cabal / stack?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I'm looking at the following module: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/boxes-0.1.4/docs/src/Text-PrettyPrint-Boxes.html

Which has contents of:

```
module Text.PrettyPrint.Boxes
    ( -- * Constructing boxes
#ifdef TESTING
      Box(Box, content)
#else
      Box
#endif
```

How can I enable / define the `TESTING` value - for development purposes? Ideally I'd like to have this built / enabled within a GHCi session.

Comment: if you call `stack test` the flag is set automatically - right now there is no cabal flag to enable this CPP flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to correct myself - the comment I gave is totally and utterly wrong.

```
> git clone git://github.com/treeowl/boxes.git
> cd boxes
> stack init
> stack ghci --ghc-options=-DTESTING
split-0.2.3.2: using precompiled package
boxes-0.1.4: configure (lib)
Configuring boxes-0.1.4...
boxes-0.1.4: initial-build-steps (lib)
Completed 2 action(s).
Configuring GHCi with the following packages: boxes
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from ...
[1 of 1] Compiling Text.PrettyPrint.Boxes ( .../boxes/Text/PrettyPrint/Boxes.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Text.PrettyPrint.Boxes.
Loaded GHCi configuration from /tmp/ghci28386/ghci-script
*Text.PrettyPrint.Boxes Text.PrettyPrint.Boxes> :t content 
content :: Box -> Content
```

just works fine.

Comment: This seems to only work when `stack ghci` is invoked on the `boxes` project rather then when it is included as a dependency via cabal.

Comment: you can send a pull request to boxes and provide a cabal flag, and use your github repo in the meantime, stack has built in options to use a repo as a source; for cabal i haven't used it in a while so I don't know if this is an option here.

Comment: if you need the `content` function for something other than testing purposes - I would ask the maintainer about the intent of hiding said function! There are plenty of things that are convenient, but increase some risk or another when used.